# java.io.FileNotFoundException log4j

Tags: java

I'm running into a issue, currently I'm getting the below error. Of course this is due to the fact that the user doesn't have access to the C: that's the not the issue. The issue is that I cannot find any references to:

- log4j
- org.apache.log4j
- org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator

I've looked in the class paths, imports for all the classes that make up the program, XML Files Associated with the project and I cannot find any references to the items.

I need to know how to track down where this is being referenced so that I can remove it from the project.

Error Example

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: c:\javalog\jhook.log (Access is denied)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.openAppend(Native Method)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.setFile(FileAppender.java:290)
at org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender.setFile(RollingFileAppender.java:194)
at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.activateOptions(FileAppender.java:164)
at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.activate(PropertySetter.java:257)
at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parseAppender(DOMConfigurator.java:285)
at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.findAppenderByName(DOMConfigurator.java:171)
at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.findAppenderByReference(DOMConfigurator.java:184)
at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parseChildrenOfLoggerElement(DOMConfigurator.java:502)
at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parseRoot(DOMConfigurator.java:471)
at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parse(DOMConfigurator.java:921)
at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.doConfigure(DOMConfigurator.java:790)
at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.doConfigure(DOMConfigurator.java:682)
at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.configure(DOMConfigurator.java:811)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.eglue.jhook.logging.Log4jLogger.internalInvokeStaticMethod(Log4jLogger.java:94)
at com.eglue.jhook.logging.Log4jLogger.<init>(Log4jLogger.java:19)
at com.eglue.jhook.logging.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:22)
at com.eglue.jhook.jni.ValuePair.<clinit>(ValuePair.java:11)
at com.eglue.jhook.jni.DataEnvelope.addValue(DataEnvelope.java:52)
at com.eglue.jhook.jni.HookManager.createMMFServer(HookManager.java:169)
at com.eglue.jhook.jni.HookManager.<init>(HookManager.java:116)
at com.eglue.jhook.Hook.init(Hook.java:43)
at com.eglue.jhook.Hook.guiInitialized(Hook.java:38)
at com.sun.java.accessibility.util.EventQueueMonitor.maybeNotifyAssistiveTechnologies(EventQueueMonitor.java:233)
at com.sun.java.accessibility.util.ComponentEvtDispatchThread.run(EventQueueMonitor.java:649)
```

Any help/ideas ,

Comment: Did you check in the constructor for `com.eglue.jhook.jni.ValuePair`?

Comment: You seem to be using a thirdparty library called `jhook`. that refers log4j internally.

Answer (score 0):

I'd faced this same issue once where a third party library used by me had a copy of log4j internally.

The following code will give the location from where the log4j is loaded

```
DOMConfigurator.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();
```

From this you can find out the location of the probable configuration file